# Android change developer option settings through code

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which I have to change background process limit to 1 which is available in developer options. Is it possible to change the Developer setting through code?

Comment: Device must be rooted!

Comment: It is rooted. But can u help with the parameters (code) to change the settings

Answer (score -1):

I found solution of my problem here:
https://github.com/flode/SetAndroidProcessLimit